# Getting Server Error while connecting to MS Sql from Android/Volley

Tags: php, android, sql-server, android-volley

I am using Volley for my Android app to fetch data from my server. It is working perfectly on my local windows machine with XAMPP 5.6.

I deployed it on windows server (IIS with PHP). The requests are running properly when i checked it using postman. But when I am checking it from my android code it is returning **`ServerError`**.

I checked further, If i comment out `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`  line from my code, it works on `IIS/PHP`.

Is there any setting required to run it from android app? It is running and giving desired result if i m running it from postman.

My Code

```
private void getclient(final String clientCode) {
    try {
        String URL = Global.APIURL + Global.getclient;            

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        CustomRequest strRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, params, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Global.ShowLog("Response getclient:" + response);
                Global.hideProgressDialog();
                try {
                    if (response != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(response)) {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (jObj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Global.ShowAlert(ThisPage.this, jObj.getString("message"));
                        } else {
                            JSONArray jsonArrayData=jObj.getJSONArray("data");
                            if(jsonArrayData.length()>0){

                                startActivity(new Intent(ThisPage.this, Login.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Global.ShowLog("Response Login(Error):" + error.getMessage());                   
            }
        }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                    
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("partycd", clientCode);

                return params;
            }
        };

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Global.hideProgressDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.

Changed the line :

> headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

to :

> headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8");